# Rasperry Pi2 Intalling Pillow

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

i have the following problem, i tried to install luma.matrix on my Raspberry Pi2. But the setup is aborted with the following message:

```
Processing Pillow-4.1.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-A_OEki/Pillow-4.1.0/setup.cfg
Running Pillow-4.1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-A_OEki/Pillow-4.1.0/egg-dist-tmp-SmW0g3
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution


The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 329, in _handle_workers
    debug('worker handler exiting')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Exception TypeError: TypeError("'NoneType' object does not support item deletion",) in <Finalize object, dead> ignored
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 353, in _handle_tasks
    debug('task handler got sentinel')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 67, in <module>
    "Operating System :: Unix"
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 117, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 411, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 654, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 701, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 746, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1123, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 673, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 699, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 880, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1119, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1105, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 258, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 169, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 144, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 255, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 285, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-A_OEki/Pillow-4.1.0/setup.py", line 756, in <module>

setuptools.sandbox.UnpickleableException: RequiredDependencyException('\n\nThe headers or library files could not be found for zlib,\na required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.\n\nPlease see the install instructions at:\n   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html\n\n',)
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 284, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 284, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The same problem when i try pip intall pillow. Zlib is already installed... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps.

Fix broken packages `sudo apt-get -f install`. Eventually clean and update the package list `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`.

> Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL.

Uninstall PIL `sudo apt-get remove python-pil`.

> We do not provide binaries for Linux. Most major Linux distributions, including Fedora, Debian/Ubuntu and ArchLinux include Pillow in packages that previously contained PIL e.g. python-imaging. Please consider using native operating system packages first to avoid installation problems and/or missing library support later.

Install Pillow (on Unix-like systems) : `sudo apt-get install python-imaging`

I believe `apt` will install the require dependencies if it does not these are the prerequisites you will need `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms1-dev`

More about Pillow's installation, [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and [here](https://www.pkimber.net/howto/python/modules/pillow.html).

Comment: Tried the steps, but no success, the same :( I also did everything in the links, but the same :/  When i try pip install pillow i get the same error, but the max7219 library need "pillow" ...

Comment: Downloaded the source and tried to install, the same: The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Comment: Ok now it works, i do the following: sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev then make install zlib...

Comment: Oh, OK, awesome.